# How Can I Include Customized phtml file in email template

Tags: magento

I am trying to send coupon code with email on new account registration. For that I created email template `system > transactional emails`.

Here in this email template I have included coupon.phtml file which is located at `app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/email/coupon.phtml` using below code.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="email_coupon" template="email/coupon.phtml"}}
```

But this is not working. I am not getting any html which I have added in coupon.html. Please guide where I have mistaken.

Comment: you might be more successful on magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes, I have asked this question on magento.stackexchange.com. I got the solution. thanks buddy

Comment: Please post a link to the answer you found.